# Get access to an object's property using bracket notation in dart

Tags: properties, dart, dart-html

I try to do the following:

```dart
var properties = ["height" , "width"];
for (var prop in properties){
  div.style[prop] = otherdiv.style[prop];
}
```

But dart doesn't seem to accept this bracket notation, is there any other way to access a property using a string in dart ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `getPropertyValue` and `setProperty` methods like

```dart
div.style.setProperty(prop, otherdiv.style.getPropertyValue(prop));
```

Comment: Thanks, only I think it must be `getPropertyValue` instead of `getProperty`.

Comment: This only works for DOM objects. For general Dart objects, there is no way to access properties from a computed name. That's a deliberate language choice - it makes it possible to optimize object layout differently when it doesn't have to allow unpredictable access. If you really need to dynamically access properties by name (or, preferably, by Symbol), you need to use the Mirror library to do the reflection.

Comment: You are right, this is only for DOM elements from `dart:html`. There is no way for normal Dart classes except reflection (server/command-line only) or code generation. I'd suggest json_serializable or built_value for that.